# Save output of a php file in a html file

Tags: php, html, file

I am having a php file which executes some code to generate a html file.Its like I m having a form from which some data will be posted to x.php file, which gives a output(a webpage). I want to save that output in a html file.What the most efficient way of doing this.?

**EDIT**
I want to save it on sever side. Actually the thing is i want to create pdf file for that.. I wrote everything else.Now the thing is i want to save the output in a html page.So that i can convert it into pdf file..

Comment: Please clarify "save". Is the output your script makes not already HTML? Where do you want to save it to, the client's PC?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// Start output buffering
ob_start();
// run code in x.php file
// ...
// saving captured output to file
file_put_contents('filename.htm', ob_get_contents());
// end buffering and displaying page
ob_end_flush();
```

If you cannot use the [ob_* functions](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php), you can also write the form to a variable and then save that variable.

Comment: replace ob_end_flush(); by ob_end_clean(); if you don't want to send the output to the browser

Answer (score 1):

using `ob_*` functions such as `ob_get_contents()`, a php script can catch it's output.

Answer (score 1):

Look at ob functions (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) that allows you to capture every output (echo, print, etc...) from the page.

Answer (score 0):

probably with ob_start and output_callback see http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php