# Save output of a php file to a two html pages

Tags: php

I have a php script to calculate and display information about administrators and managers. The php file is status_report.php. I use param (called "type") to distinct two users. I am using this script.  It create a file for admins, but doesn't create a file for managers. 
Please help me to get it works.

```
session_start();
ob_start();
$_GET['type'] ="admin";
include('status_report.php'); 
file_put_contents('reports/admins.html', ob_get_contents());
ob_end_clean();

// for manages
ob_start();
$_GET['type'] ="manager";
include('status_report.php'); 
file_put_contents('reports/managers.html', ob_get_contents());
ob_end_clean();
```

This is an extension of this question- [Save output of a php file in a html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522609/save-output-of-a-php-file-in-a-html-file)

Comment: What happens if you swap around the two sections of code, so the managers file is created first?

Comment: I just checked it now by swapping them. yes. It serves only the first one. So managers.html is created if  I put it as first

Comment: I'd guess that there's something going on in `status_report.php`, in that case - you're including the file twice, so if there are functions in there, they'll be re-declared and PHP will complain about that.

Comment: Any alternatives to achieve what i needs without duplicating code ?

Comment: If you've got functions in your `status_report` file, you can move them into this file - they'll be declared once there, but still accessible from the report file. Otherwise, without knowing what's in there, I'm just guessing.

Comment: show errors on page! maybe the second include clashes! error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: I included the lines. This is only thing in the page -          Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\wamp\www\status_report.php on line 2

Comment: if you use classes with same names it would fail and php gives no error in some versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a method to enclose the repeating things

```
function f1($params){
    ob_start();
    $_GET['type'] =$params;
    $page = 'reports/'. $params  .'.html';
    include('status_report.php'); 
    file_put_contents($page, ob_get_contents());
    ob_end_clean();
}
```

then call it for number of times

```
f1("admin");
f1("managers");
```

....